# Best practice migrating a large amount of sub sites from 2013 to Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, migration, sub-site

I have an on-prem (2013) site with 200+ subsites all created from the same template with the same document library just because users wanted to re-use the same filenames (and document library names) for different suppliers.

So 1 site for each supplier with a portal site with hyperlinks to the subsites on top.

Since we decided to phase out our on-prem environment this site will have to be migrated to SPO.

Is it wise to move this behemoth of sites to O365 just as is? Or is their a better restructured alternative I'm missing? I'm curious about the experts experience on this or if others have experienced a similar migration.

Comment: given the fact that SPO is Site Collection centered(given the functionalities by the hubs), i believe your best bet is to restructure to a Site Collection-wise deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint hub sites help you meet the needs of your organization by connecting and organizing sites based on project, department, division, region, etc. making it easier to:

- Discover related content such as news and other site activities
- Apply common navigation, branding, and site structure across
  associated sites
- Search across all associated sites

SharePoint administrators determine how many hub sites can be created in your organization, who can associate sites with each hub site, and whether associating a site to a hub requires approval.

Therefore, we recommend that you reorganize the site structure because it is not advisable to have too many subsites in SharePoint online.

You can read "**[Planning your SharePoint hub sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites)**" articel to plan your enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

Considering SPO where you have hub site concept I would suggest you re organize the sites. Not good to have so many subsites.

Read more about Planning your hub site. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites